# Где найти Autocomplete из Android Studio?

Tags: java, ide

Разрабатываю свою Java IDE, необходимо найти autocomplete фичу. Возможно, есть какой-то опенсорс репозиторий или можно как-то вырвать этот механизм из Android Studio? Кто в танке autocomplete это функция автодополнения при вводе, например, когда мы пишем `Str`  под курсором появляется окно с вариантами автодополнения (`String`, `StringBuilder` и др.)

Comment: Простите, но или я совсем не в теме проблем программистов на яве или сам автокомплит меньшая из проблемм и если вы уже решили остальные проблемы - эта часть сложности составлять для вас не должна.... =) я сейчас о хотябы подсветке синтаксиса и правильного определения зоны видимости переменных, эти проблеммы у вас решены?

Comment: Ахахахахаха, смешно(sorry))). Зачем вам это? Чем вас не устраивает IntelliJ? Как уже писал @ВладимирКлыков, это - одна из наименьших проблем. Если хотите, посмотрите исходники IntelliJ на GitHub. Или вот, может [это](https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/424763/) поможет вам.

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, я разрабатываю мобильную IDE, приложение использует внутреннюю систему Linux и обращается к ней через proot. Уже настроен Gradle и Lint. Работа пока идёт через командную строку. IDE как для простых Java программ, так и для Android приложений. Сборка идёт с помощью Gradle, настроен механизм запуска Lint и вывода ошибок/предупреждений по коду в файл. Сейчас решил забежать вперёд и просто узнать если ли автодополнение в опенсорсе. Подсветки синтаксиса нет, так как я ещё не приступал к интерфейсу. А что значит "правильное определение зоны видимости переменных"?

Comment: @Anton Sorokin, почему вам смешно?) Я разрабатываю мобильную IDE уровня Android Studio и хочу исправить проблему отсутствия нормальных программ для разработки прямо на телефоне.

Comment: Смешно потому что автодополнение это "бонус" после того как вы научите свою программу правильно светить синтаксис и определять зону видимости =) чтобы "дополнить" до конца строку надо "знать" что в этой области видимости может находится, и фильтровать из этого списка то что подходит вам =) т.е. вам нужно реализовать **динамический синтаксический анализатор**, а это ох какая непростая задача =)

Comment: @Flippy потому что это очень-очень-очень сложно, и над этим несколько лет трудятся много(а не один) людей, причем профессионалы. IDE уровня AS вам в одиночку, да еще и на смарт, не удастся скорее всего разработать(sorry, если что). Да и к тому же писать программы на смартфоне - это жесть, вы уж поверьте. Точнее, на смарте вообще невозможно разработать программу.

Comment: @Flippy тем более, чем вас не устраивает множество уже сделанных IDE?
Пример - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duy.compiler.javanide&hl=ru

Comment: @AntonSorokin, вы уж простите что вмешиваюсь, со многим солидарен, кроме одного =) На смарте вполне комфортно можно работать, особенно если подключить к нему мышку клаву и монитор, и на сегодня это не фантастика =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ааа, ну да. Я имел ввиду трудности с написанием кода на экранной клаве, нормально быстро писать практически невозможно. Так же маленькие экраны смартфонов - на них нельзя вместить большие куски кода.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ладно мышку и клавиатуру - их спокойно можно носить с собой, но вот монитор? Какой-то портативный, но при этом с нормальным (по размерам) экраном?

Comment: @Flippy насчет "IDE уровня Android Studio" вы всё-таки загнули. Можно попытаться сделать что-то на уровня Notepad++ (подсветка ключевых слов, скобок и простой (по имеющимся в файле словам, а также по ключевым и по какому-то фиксированному набору стандартных классов) автокомплит)

Comment: @Regent но к счастью, таких IDE уже куча, и Flippy не придется делать свою :). А если ему не нравится функционал IDE, то код [этой](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duy.compiler.javanide&hl=ru) например есть на GitHub, и он может допилить все что хочет.

Comment: @Regent кейс использования немного другой =) пришел на работу, у тебя телефон цепанулся к монитору клаве мышке.... пришел домой - там тоже самое =) монитор\клава\мышка - докстанция, телефон - системник =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Но... Зачем? Ни одна IDE на смарт не заменит удобство IntelliJ или VS. А что-бы код с работы использовать дома можно юзать гит.

Comment: @AntonSorokin Эмм, простите я и так использую не смарт в качестве дистанционного рабочего места, у меня есть для этого RDP =) а пример был - ибо была проба как такое заведется, и оно вполне успешно завелось =) сегодня мощности телефонов вполне позволяют редактировать исходники.... p.s. Не встретил ни одной среды под яву которая бы не жрала ОЗУ как не в себя. Сравните по прожорливости ваши примеры хотябы с Delphi XE5-10, удивитесь но средний смарт современный вывез бы такое без проблем.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Вы не поняли. Вы написали что приходите на работу, подключаетесь к смарту, ведете разработку, приходите домой, так же ведете разработку со смарта. Почему не с пк в IntelliJ, VS code и т.п.?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ведь в них намного удобнее вести разработку чем в android-ide

Comment: @AntonSorokin Перечитайте первое предложение того поста в котором я "якобы" говорю что я так делаю =) я там указал что кейс использования смарта с монитором это не таскать его(монитор) с собой, а цеплять к док станции в виде монитора... и снова повторюсь мощностей среднего смартфона достаточно чтобы запустить на нем среду **Delphi XE 5 - 10**, полноценную, ту что для компьютера.

Comment: Простите прошлый комент разросся, **удобнее** -  дело лишь привычки, мне удобнее некоторые вещи делать в обычном блокноте нежели запускать среду программирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как известно, AS - это просто переделанная IntelliJ. Ответ на вопрос - скорее всего в [исходниках IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community). Скорее всего - [вот](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/spellchecker).

У [этой IDE под Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duy.compiler.javanide&hl=ru) вроде как есть autocomplite. Вот ее [страница](https://github.com/tranleduy2000/javaide) на GitHub.